# I don't understand why my css won't use shadow

Tags: css

It should be easy but it isn't cooperating and it must be a user (me) error.

CSS

```
.shadow {
  color:#8C8C8C
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px;
}
```

HTML

```
<h2 class="shadow">Description</h2>
```

Comment: Post code as text, not as screenshots, please.

Comment: Done thanks for letting me know

Comment: Missing a semicolon after the color rule.

Comment: Kay, answered. I don't know how to flag it as answered though. I see no button.

Comment: I figured out how to mark as answered. Thanks so much for being timely with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you see the color code in an IDE, you will see there is a mismatch in your properties, and that's because you are missing a semi-colon

```css
.shadow {
  color: #8C8C8C;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="shadow">Description</h2>
```